# Perl data process

Tags: perl

I have data something like below:

```
$data = [
    [qw(x y)],
    [qw(x)  ],
    [qw(x z)],
    [qw(z)  ], 
];
```

And I would like to convert this into something like below:

```
 [ x, x, x, z ]
```

The rule is starting with first element, find the common element between the first two elements, if found any common, the assign the common value to both elements i.e. x. Now pick the second and third element, find if any common value between them then do the same and carry on until you reach the last element. if you find common value between the last two pairs then only assign it to the last element.

Comment: *" if found any common, the assign the common value to both elements"* So the value of the first two elements of the result is always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to calculate some kind of intersection of your data points?
I would do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;

use Data::Dumper;

my @data = (
    [qw(x y)],
    [qw(x)  ],
    [qw(x z)],
    [qw(z)  ],
);

sub intersect {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;

    my $union = {};
    my $isect = {};

    foreach my $e (@$a, @$b) {
        $union->{$e}++ && $isect->{$e}++;
    }

    return keys %$isect;
}

my @result = ();

for my $i (0..$#data - 1) {
    my @intersection = intersect($data[$i], $data[$i+1]);

    if (scalar @intersection) {
        my $isect = shift @intersection;

        if ($i == 0) {
            push @result, $isect;
        }

        push @result, $isect;
    }
    else {
        die sprintf("Data points do not intersect at position %d", $i+1);
    }
}

print Dumper \@result;
```

Running this script gives me the following output:

```
$ ./intersection.pl 
$VAR1 = [
          'x',
          'x',
          'x',
          'z'
        ];
```

Hope this helps.

Another `intersect` method is also available in the `Array::Utils` package on CPAN.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using the `intersect` function from the [`Array::Utils`](https://metacpan.org/module/Array::Utils) module. It may need installing as it isn't a core module.

I'm not certain that I have your specification correctly. You are syaing that you want common elements between the first two list added *twice*. Is that right? And you don't say what happens if you have more than one common item between any pair of lists. This solution just adds the first one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Array::Utils 'intersect';

my $data = [ ['x', 'y'], ['x'], ['x', 'z'], ['z'] ];

my @result;

for my $i ( 1 .. $#$data ) {
  my @pair = @{$data}[$i-1, $i];
  my @common = intersect(@{$pair[0]}, @{$pair[1]});
  push @result, $common[0];
  push @result, $common[0] if $i == 1;
}

printf "[ %s ]\n", join ', ', @result;
```

**output**

```
[ x, x, x, z ]
```

---

**Update**

If it is a problem for you to install the module then you can simply copy this subroutine definition to the end of the code, and remove the `use Array::Utils` statement.

```
sub intersect(\@\@) {
  my %e = map { $_ => undef } @{$_[0]};
  return grep { exists( $e{$_} ) } @{$_[1]};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Slightly different approach to David Kitcher-Jones answer.

Comment: You're creating most of the hashes twice.